# Trying to pull out text characters from a field using a calculated field in Tableau to determine type of invoice

Tags: tableau-api

I have a field `[DistributorInvoiceNumber]` that has adjustments and credits recorded at the end of the number as `A` for Adjustment or `CR` for a credit or `ACR` for reversal (horrible set up I know).  I am trying to find a way to create a calculated field in Tableau that can set these types of `[DistributorInvoiceNumbers]` apart.  For example, `505060100A` would be flagged as Adjustment or `779466ACR` would be flagged as Adjustment Credit.  Does anyone have any ideas how to do this?  Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
IF  RIGHT([DistributorInvoiceNumbers],1) = 'A' THEN
    'Adjustment'
ELSEIF RIGHT([DistributorInvoiceNumbers],3) = 'ACR' THEN
    'Reversal'
ELSEIF RIGHT([DistributorInvoiceNumbers],2) = 'CR' THEN
    'Credit'
ELSE
    'Unknown'    
END
```

Comment: @Alex Thanks for the revisions! I hadn't thought about the effect the order would have.